# Graph Theory - Players problem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have written proofs for 3 problems and I am hoping someone can point out any flaws in my logic. Let me start with some definitions.

In a n-tournament (complete digraph) with n number of players, there is a "x beats y" or $x \rightarrow y$ relationship which is antisymmetric. Also we will say that the score of A is the number of players A beats.

We say that a player k is an alpha player if, for every player r different from k, either k beats r or else there is some player s such that k beats s and s beats r.

We will define the set P as the set of all players in a tournament and we will assume that every tournament has an alpha.

The problems

1. Prove that in every tournament if a player is beaten then it is beaten by a alpha player.
2. Prove that no tournament can have exactly 2 alphas.
3. Prove that there is no 4-player tournament in which every player is an alpha.

Proofs:

1. Suppose player $c\in P$ is beaten then the set of players who have beaten c, lets call it D and $D \subseteq P$, is not empty. If a player z has not beaten c then c must have beaten this player,so z belongs to the set of players beaten by c, call it L and $L \subseteq P$. Since we assumed that every tournament has an alpha then the set D must have an alpha named A. if A beats c directly then A must beat all the players in L through c so A beats every player in P. Therefore c is beaten by an alpha A.
2. We will prove by contradiction. Suppose a tournament has two alphas, w and z. Then w beats z directly or through another player so z is beaten by an alpha. Now z must beat w directly or indirectly so w is beaten by an alpha. However, since the relationship is anti symmetric  they cannot beat each other directly. And if w beats z through a player k and z beats w  then k beats w through z then k is also an alpha. This contradicts our assumption.
3. Say we have four players A,B,C and D. In each of the possible pairings  a player can score a point so there are 6 points available. The minimum score of a player is 1 otherwise a player with a score of 0 cant be an alpha. If player score is 3 then the rest of the players will have 1 score point each but this also means that none of the other players can beat A so A is the only alpha. A player with 1 point, leaves 5 points left which can be distributed so that another player has 1 point and the remaining two get 2 points each. Now suppose A and D have 2 points each, one of them, say A, must beat a player with 1 point, say C, and a player with 2 points, and the other, say D, must beat both players who have 1 point. Since A only beats C and D then B beats A. In any way, C cant beat D so C is not an alpha. This can be shown if the variables names are interchanged.

Any hints or feedback will be appreciated. Thank you all!

Comment: What do you mean by "every group slash tournament" has an alpha? What is a group in this context?

Comment: we can consider a tournament a group of players where the anti symmetric relation of x beats y happens. I will edit my post to avoid confusions.

Comment: "then k beats w through z then k is also an alpha" - I don't think that's a correct deduction. Beating an alpha doesn't necessarily make you an alpha according to the definition. In order to show $k$ is alpha, you need to prove it beats *all* others in one or two hops.

Comment: Yes thats correct but let me elaborate a little, $w \rightarrow k \rightarrow z$ and $z \rightarrow w$ or put differently $k \rightarrow z \rightarrow w$ therefore k is an alpha by definition. do you not agree?

Comment: You got it. I will edit my post to make it more clear.

Comment: You proved #1 by showing that every tournament S with more than one player contains a smaller tournament T such that every alpha of T is also an alpha of S. This provides an alternative proof, by strong induction, of the fact that every tournament has an alpha. (The other proof I'm familiar with is by observing that, if player x's score $\ge$ player y's score, then x either beats y or beats someone who beats y; thus the player with the highest score, or any player tied for the highest score, is an alpha.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proofs for 1 and 3 look fine to me. In your argument for 2, you have not justified the claim "then k is also an alpha." In fact, here is a counterexample showing that it can't be justified.

Consider a tournament with 5 players: w,z,u,v,k. Suppose that:
w beats u,v,k.
z beats w,u.
u beats v,k.
v beats z,k.
k beats z.

Now w and z are alphas; z beats w directly, and w beats z through k, but k is not an alpha.

This is a counterexample to your argument. It's not a counterexample to 2, because z is also an alpha.

(I could give you hints for proving 2, but you didn't ask for any, so I won't spoil your fun.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I was thinking maybe I can use problem 1 to prove problem 2.

Comment: Suppose w and z are both alphas. Then w beats z directly or indirectly, so z is beaten by alpha by problem 1. This alpha must be w. Likewise, we find w is beaten by an alpha and this must be z. However since the relation is antisymmetric then that's not possible. Thoughts?

Comment: @rhoward Looks fine to me. No need to present it as proof by contradiction. If w and z both alphas, one must beat the other directly, say w beats z. Some player must beat w directly, by problem 1 w is beaten by an alpha, can't be w or z, so there's your third alpha.

Comment: That is true. Thank you.